# Using Python String Formatting with Changing Lists Sizes

Tags: python, string, list

how do I print the string line without preparing from advance the {} places. Because now my function needed only 6 places, but if I'll change the input `(n,m)` I'll need different number of {}. How to define it?

```
def all_pairs_sum(m,n):
    sum = 0
    mult = []
    for m in range(1,m+1):
        for n in range(1,n+1):
            l = m*n
            mult.append(l)
            sum = sum + m*n
            print(m," * ", n, " = ", l)
    print("{}+{}+{}+{}+{}+{} =".format(*mult))
    return sum

print (all_pairs_sum(2,3))
```

Comment: `'+'.join(mult)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) feature added in Python 3.6. Also notice that `sum` is a function from Python standard library. It's better not to name your variables that name. As you can see in my example I called it `total`

```
def all_pairs_sum(m,n):
    total = 0
    mult = []
    for m in range(1, m + 1):
      for n in range(1 , n + 1):
          l = m * n
          mult.append(l)
          total += l
          print(f"{m} * {n} = {l:>2d}")
    print(f"{' + '.join(map(str, mult))} = {sum(mult)}")
    return total

print(all_pairs_sum(2, 5))
```

Output:

```
1 * 1 =  1
1 * 2 =  2
1 * 3 =  3
1 * 4 =  4
1 * 5 =  5
2 * 1 =  2
2 * 2 =  4
2 * 3 =  6
2 * 4 =  8
2 * 5 = 10
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = 45
45
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the method `format()` you have a definite number of replacement fields `{}`. You can use this solution:

```
l = list(range(5))
print(' + '.join(str(i) for i in l), ' = ', sum(l))
# 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4  =  10
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def get_msg_template(n):
    tmp =  '{}+' * n
    return tmp[:-1]

print(get_msg_template(4))
```

Output:

```
 {}+{}+{}+{}
```

Comment: You also can use `join` here: `' + '.join(['{}'] * n)`

Comment: also helps. I used for my code `print(' + '.join(['{}'] * n*m).format(*mult))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for printing out the string representation of summed values, you can use something like this:

`print("+".join(str(x) for x in mult))`